# Do any secular scholars affirm that 1 Corinthians 15:3-5 is an early creed?

Tags: 1-corinthians, paul, history, commentary

In 1 Corinthians 15:3-6, St. Paul provides us with an early historical creed, this creed was something that St. Paul tells us that he had received (1 Corinthians 15:3) and lists those who were apparent eyewitnesses to the resurrection, including five hundred people at once. But do any secular scholars affirm that 1 Corinthians 15:3-6 is an early historical creed that pre-dates St. Paul?

> For I delivered to you first of all that which I also received: that
> Christ died for our sins according to the Scriptures,
>
> And that He was buried, and that He rose again the third day according
> to the Scriptures,
>
> And that He was seen by Cephas, then by the twelve. 6 After that He
> was seen by over five hundred brethren at once, of whom the greater
> part remain to the present, but some have fallen asleep.

Comment: This might better be asked on SE-Chrstianity. The OP is asking 'what scholars affirm' and is not asking about the text itself. Please see the Tour and the Help (below) as to the purpose and functioning of the site. Welcome to SE-BH.

Comment: Your assertion is, in my experience, the most commonly held - 1 Cor 15:3-6 appears to either an early creed or an early Christian hymn.

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for joining the group.  Please remember to take the tour (link bottom left) to better understand how this site works and how it is different from others.

Comment: I added the "commentary" tag to establish the relevance of the question here. The fact that it seeks expertise  about a biblical passage from secular scholars should not be disqualifying.

Answer (score 4):

If by "secular scholar" the OP means a scholar who is a non-believer, then yes -- there are many such scholars who see the quote in the OP as an early creed, perhaps a creed that was part of a poetic liturgy. Indeed, this is the general view of biblical scholarship whether secular or ecclesiastical. One such non-believing scholar is [Bart Erhman](https://ehrmanblog.org/the-core-of-pauls-gospel/), who says of this passage:

> [Paul] indicates that he “passed on” this message of Jesus’ death and
> resurrection as he himself had “received” it..  “Delivering to you” and “having received” are code language in ancient Jewish circles for traditions that are passed down from a teacher to his students: during his studies the teacher “receives” a tradition and then in his teaching he “delivers” it to his own followers...  He is actually quoting a piece of poetry, or possibly a creed, that had been in circulation among the Christians.   You will notice that vv. 3-5 are very lapidary and direct and that you can divide the lines into two major parts, each of the parts having three statements, and that the statements of part 2 correspond to the statements of part 1.  If you laid it out graphically, it would look like this:

```
That Christ died for our sins

in accordance with the scriptures.

and that he was buried;

That he was raised on the third day

in accordance with the scriptures,

and that he appeared to Cephas, then to the twelve.
```

Ehrman concludes:

> This is a very carefully and intentionally crafted statement. It is
> widely thought that it may have been some kind of creed that was
> recited in the Christian churches, or possibly a statement of faith
> that was to be recited by recent converts at their baptism, a creed
> that is being quoted by Paul here (not composed by him when writing
> the letter).

Comment: I had considered Bart Erhman, but I wasn't totally sure! +1 for me.

Answer (score 2):

These are two that you may find worth checking out:

Gerd Lüdemann -  German scholar and professor of history and literature of early Christianity, has written on the historical Jesus and early Christian theology.  He says that it dates within “the first two years after the crucifixion of Jesus,” [[1]](https://www.girltalkapologetics.com/post/why-is-1-corinthians-15-3-7-so-important-for-resurrection-studies)

Paula Fredriksen - A scholar of early Christianity and Professor Emerita of the Humanities at Boston University, Fredriksen has discussed the creed in her works on the historical Jesus and the development of Christian beliefs. She recognizes the creed as an early expression of Christian faith. [[2]](https://www.caspari.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Mishkan79.pdf#page=41&zoom=100,0,913)

> I know in their own terms, what they saw was the raised Jesus. That’s
> what they say, and then all the historic evidence we have afterwards
> attests to their conviction that that’s what they saw. I’m not saying
> that they really did see the raised Jesus. I wasn’t there. I don’t
> know what they saw. But I do know as an historian, that they must have
> seen something. The disciples’ conviction that they had seen the risen
> Christ, their relocation to Jerusalem, their principled inclusion of
> Gentiles as Gentile—all these are historical bedrock, facts known past
> doubting about the earliest community after Jesus’ death.

Fredriksen’s comments came during an interview with the late ABC journalist Peter Jennings for his documentary The
Search for Jesus, which first aired in July 2000. Emphasis added.

https://crossexamined.org/the-evidential-value-of-1-corinthians-153-8-to-the-case-for-the-resurrection/

Answer (score 0):

Why would you care at all what a "secular scholar" thinks?  Romans speaks CLEARLY about the unsaved mind that it is CARNAL which is at open WAR with God.

Our FAITH while not simply blind faith, can not be dependent on what the WORLD thinks.

Comment: Welcome to the group, Rob. Please do take the Tour to understand how it works and what constitutes a good answer. We try to avoid impugning each others' faith, and the site is open to all points of view, Christian, Jewish, secular, etc.  " We welcome Jewish, Christian, Atheist, and other viewpoints, as long as they take seriously the process of understanding Biblical texts. "

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).